# How to reverse the fields order when generate JSON with argonaut?

Tags: json, scala, argonaut

With [argonaut](http://argonaut.io), I can generate some JSON as:

```
def toJson(user:User) = ("id" := user.id) ->: ("name" := user.name) ->: jEmptyObject
```

But it will generate json with reversed order:

```
{
   "name": "myname",
   "id": "123"
}
```

Actually I want it to be:

```
{
   "id": "123",
   "name": "myname"
}
```

Is there any way to do that? I don't want to write it as:

```
("name" := user.name) ->: ("id" := user.id) ->: jEmptyObject
```

I want to find a way to write them in the same order

Comment: There is no difference between the two orders.  JSON "objects" are unordered.

Comment: This json will be read by human eyes, so I want to have some kind of "order"

Comment: So, extract the "id" and "name" values and present them in the order you wish.  JSON is not intended to be a presentation form.

Answer (score 0):

Define the field in that order first in Encoder as -

```scala
implicit def EncodeUserJson: EncodeJson[User] = EncodeJson[User]((p: User) ⇒
("id" := p.id) ->:
  ("name" := p.name) ->: jEmptyObject)
```

Next use nospace but preserve order -

```scala
val t = PrettyParams.nospace.copy(preserveOrder = 
true).pretty(user.asJson)
```

when you print t (which is stringified user) you'd see the order.